# Simulated Binary Crossover (SBX) crossover operator in Scala genetic algorithm (GA) library

Tags: java, scala, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm, mathematical-optimization

I work on a very little research team to create/adapt a Genetic Algorithm library in Scala for distributed computation with Scientific Worklow System, in our case  we use the open source OpenMole software (http://www.openmole.org/).

Recently, i try to understand and re-implement the SBX crossover operator written in JMetal Metaheuristics library (http://jmetal.sourceforge.net/) to adapt it in functionnal version in our Scala library.

I write some code, but i need our advice or your validation about the SBX defined into java library, because the source code ([src in svn](http://jmetal.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jmetal/trunk/jmetal/operators/crossover/SBXCrossover.java?revision=288&view=markup)) doesn't appear equal to the original equation written here : http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.33.7291&rep=rep1&type=pdf at page 30, in annexe A

[image: BetaEquation]

First question, i don't understand the java version of JMetal, why  they use two different beta values ?!

- **beta1** which use in the equation the first arg of min[(y1 - yL), ...] and
- **beta2** which use the second arg of min [... , (yu - y2)])

**Beta** 1 and 2 are used for computation of **alpha** value and two (so here and in jmetal we have also two alpha different value alpha1 and 2) ...

Same problem/question, we have  in jmetal two computation for **betaq** (java code) or in Deb equation, result of : [image: betaoverlined]

Second question, what is the meaning of the symbol [image: betaoverlined] used in (2) and (3) procedure in pseudo-algorithm of SBX, and the difference with simple **beta** ? Especially when we want to compute children/offsprings of crossover parents, like here :

[image]

### Edit

- Correct a no-op if/else block
- Author of code in jmetal give me the link of original source code of Nsga-II algorithm, and he explain me that description of SBX by Deb differs from his implementation :/

  http://www.iitk.ac.in/kangal/codes.shtml

  I don't understand the difference between the description and the implementation in jmetal and original source code, do you have an explanation ?
- Correct if/else return for map

### Start of translation into scala

```scala
  class SBXBoundedCrossover[G <: GAGenome, F <: GAGenomeFactory[G]](rate: Random => Double = _.nextDouble) extends CrossOver [G, F] {

  def this(rate: Double) = this( _ => rate)

  def crossOver (genomes : IndexedSeq [G], factory: F) (implicit aprng : Random) = {
    val g1 = genomes.random
    val g2 = genomes.random
    val crossoverRate = rate(aprng)
    val EPS =  1.0e-14
    val numberOfVariables = g1.wrappedValues.size
    val distributionIndex = 2

    val variableToMutate = (0 until g1.wrappedValues.size).map{x => !(aprng.nextDouble < 0.5)}

    //crossover probability
    val offspring = {

      if (aprng.nextDouble < crossoverRate) {      
        (variableToMutate zip (g1.wrappedValues zip g2.wrappedValues)) map {
          case (b, (g1e, g2e)) =>
            if(b) {
              if (abs(g1e - g2e) > EPS){

                val y1 = min(g1e, g2e)
                val y2 = max(g2e, g1e)

                var yL = 0.0 //g1e.getLowerBound
                var yu = 1.0 //g1e.getUpperBound  
                var rand = aprng.nextDouble   // ui

                var beta1 = 1.0 + (2.0 * (y1 - yL)/(y2 - y1))
                var alpha1 = 2.0 - pow(beta1,-(distributionIndex+1.0))
                var betaq1 = computebetaQ(alpha1,distributionIndex,rand)

                //calcul offspring 1 en utilisant betaq1, correspond au β barre
                var c1 = 0.5 * ((y1 + y2) - betaq1 * (y2 - y1)) 

                // -----------------------------------------------

                var beta2 = 1.0 + (2.0 * (yu - y2) / (y2 - y1))
                var alpha2 = 2.0 - pow(beta2, -(distributionIndex + 1.0))

                var betaq2 = computebetaQ(alpha2,distributionIndex,rand)

                //calcul offspring2 en utilisant betaq2
                var c2 = 0.5 * ((y1 + y2) + betaq2 * (y2 - y1))

                if (c1 < yL) c1 = yL
                if (c1 > yu) c1 = yu

                if (c2 < yL) c2 = yL
                if (c2 > yu) c2 = yu   

                if (aprng.nextDouble <= 0.5) {
                  (c2,c1)
                } else {
                  (c1, c2) 
                }

              }else{
                (g1e, g2e)
              }

            }else{
              (g2e, g1e)
            }
        }

      }else{
        // not so good here ...
        (g1.wrappedValues zip g2.wrappedValues)
      }
    }
    (factory.buildGenome(offspring.map{_._1}),  factory.buildGenome(offspring.map{_._2}))
  }

  def computebetaQ(alpha:Double,  distributionIndex:Double,  rand:Double):Double = { 
    if (rand <= (1.0/alpha)){
      pow ((rand * alpha),(1.0 / (distributionIndex + 1.0)))
    } else {
      pow ((1.0 / (2.0 - rand * alpha)),(1.0 / (distributionIndex + 1.0)))
    } 
  }
```

Thanks a lot for your advice, or help in this problem.

SR

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `if (g1e < g2e){
                    var y1 = g1e
                    var y2 = g2e
                  } else {
                    var y1 = g2e
                    var y2 = g1e
                  }`?  That code has no effect.  Why not just `val y1 = min(g1e, g2e), y2 = max(g2e, g1e);`?

Comment: That whole if-else code is a No-Op.

Comment: @reyman64, isn't Scala block scoped?

Comment: @MikeSamuel, you're right, sorry, i update the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reyman64, your question is the answer I was looking for. Thank you.

I took the paper you linked and the code of Deb's implementation and tried to understand both. For that, I commented almost every line of the code. They differ only in the calculation of beta.

Since Deb used this code in his implementation of the NSGA-II, I'll stick to this version of the algorithm.

If anyone is in the same situation I was (not understanding how to implement SBX), I left my commentaries in the following gist, take a look.

https://gist.github.com/Tiagoperes/1779d5f1c89bae0cfdb87b1960bba36d

Answer (score 2):

I did an implementation of the SBX (it is called *Simulated* Binary Crossover btw) for HeuristicLab (C#). You can take a look at the implementation of our [SimulatedBinaryCrossover](http://dev.heuristiclab.com/trac/hl/core/browser/trunk/sources/HeuristicLab.Encodings.RealVectorEncoding/3.3/Crossovers/SimulatedBinaryCrossover.cs). I took the description from a different reference however (paper title: "Simulated binary crossover for continuous search space" from 1995). The full citation is given in the source code.

Comment: I correct the title of my question :)  It seems this is the first version of SBX without bounded variable management, but it's great to read a different implementation ! I read the source code tonight, thanks !

Comment: Help yourself, I checked it very thoroughly with the reference and some material that I found online (there's a helpful presentation lying around somewhere). If you find a bug, please let me know.

Comment: i have one question about your code, it seems you return only one parent, or imho a crossover return two parents no ? 
Why you compute only one part of crossover (probability < 0.5 at line 92), imho you need a `result1[i]` on line 93 and a `result2[i]` on line95, no ?

Comment: It does not matter if a crossover produces two offspring or just one. We sample twice the number of parents and produce one offspring per pair. If you return two offspring in your implementation that's fine.

Comment: Ok, it seems Deb use a different implementation compare to this paper description of SBX, we can see that in his source code of NSGA-II (see updated post)