# What does crossover index of 0.25 means in Genetic algorithm for real encoding?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, genetic-algorithm, heuristics, mutation, crossover

I am familiar with crossover and mutation indexes in binary representation but in real encoding, I came across with several articles in which *crossover index* and *mutation index* are used as parameter values.

For example, we have population size of `300` and `30` decision variables then what does crossover index = 0.25 means?

Also confused about the mutation index of `100+current generation number`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Crossover index

A number of real-coded crossover operators have been developed that create two children solutions from two parent solutions.

Maybe the papers you're reading use the **Simulated Binary Crossover** (SBX).

For this operator the **crossover index** (`η`) is a non-negative real parameter. A large value of `η` gives a higher probability for creating near parent solutions and a small value of `η` allows distant solutions to be selected as children solutions.

---

The step by step procedure for SBX algorithm is:

1. Choose a random number `u ∈ [0; 1[`.
2. Calculate `βq`:

   [image: β]
3. Compute children solutions using these equations:

   [image: children]

   Here `Xi(1, t+1)` and `Xi(2, t+1)` are the children obtained from two parents `Xi(1, t)` and `Xi(2, t)`.

A possible implementation in C is [here](https://gist.github.com/Tiagoperes/1779d5f1c89bae0cfdb87b1960bba36d) (also take a look at [Simulated Binary Crossover (SBX) crossover operator in Scala genetic algorithm (GA) library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8918625/3235496) and [Simulated Binary Crossover (SBX) crossover operator example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22457941/3235496)).

So the probability distribution for creating children solutions of continuous variables when `η=2` / `η=5` is:

[image: probability distribution]

Parents are marked with `o` and you can see how a larger value gives higher probability for creating near-parent solutions.

---

The reference paper for SBX is:

> Simulated Binary Crossover for Continuous Search Space
>
> Kalyanmoy Deb, Ram Bhushan Agrawal
>
> 1995 (PDF [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/b8ee/6b68520ae0291075cb1408046a7dff9dd9ad.pdf))

### Mutation index

The **mutation index** (`ηₘ`) is (probably) a parameter of the polynomial mutation operator suggested by Deb and Agrawal (1999).

`ηₘ` induces an effect of a perturbation of `O((b – a) / ηₘ)` in a variable, where `a` and `b` are lower and upper bounds of the variable.

Then it's reasonable to use a larger `ηₘ` for subsequent generations.

Comment: Can you help me with this code please? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61424854/9667766)